# Laravel 5.4 relationship beLongsToMany

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi i need fix returning view. I made relation and its returning array. How i can change this and i am not sure i made good function to relationship. I just trying lerning it i saw many tutorials and i know in Laravel is so kind magic tips to returning.
My function must showing events what user was joining. I think i make it but its returning array and when i try do something like that

```html
@foreach($zapisevents as $zapisevent)
      <table class="table">
      <th>{{$zapisevent->eventsave->name}}</th>
      </table>
      @endforeach
```

i got error: 
**Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /home/mariusz/Pulpit/www/szpital/resources/views/profil/profil.blade.php)**

but when i use `<th>{{$zapisevent->eventsave}}</th>` its returning array.

There is function for joining to event

```html
    public function index()
    {
     $userid = Auth::user();
     $zapisevents = User::with('eventsave')->where('id',(Auth::user()->id))->get();
     return view('profil.profil', ['userid' => $userid], ['zapisevents' => $zapisevents]);
    
    }
```

Model User:

```html
    public function eventsave()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(HomeModel::class,'save_events','users_id','events_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Model HomeModel <<<

```html
 public function usersave()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'save_events','events_id','users_id');
    }
```

Its returning:

> [{"id":5,"name":"asdasdsa","title":"Wydzial 1","start":"2017-04-04
>   03:00:00","end":"2017-04-04 07:59:00","created_at":"2017-04-01
>   18:50:40","updated_at":"2017-04-01
>   18:50:40","pivot":{"users_id":3,"events_id":5,"created_at":"2017-04-01
>   18:50:58","updated_at":"2017-04-01
>   18:50:58"}},{"id":7,"name":"kkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkkk","title":"Wydzial
>   4","start":"2017-04-01 00:00:00","end":"2017-04-01
>   23:59:59","created_at":"2017-04-01 19:54:24","updated_at":"2017-04-01
>   19:54:24","pivot":{"users_id":3,"events_id":7,"created_at":"2017-04-01
>   19:55:41","updated_at":"2017-04-01 19:55:41"}}]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the

```
@foreach($zapisevents as $zapisevent)
  <table class="table">
  <th>{{$zapisevent->eventsave->name}}</th>
  </table>
  @endforeach
```

Should ne

```
@foreach($zapisevents as $zapisevent)
  <table class="table">
 @foreach($zapisevent->eventsave as $eventSave)
  <th>{{$eventsave->name}}</th>
@endForeach
  </table>
  @endforeach
```

in you code the name property is being called in a collection of HomeModel but it needs to be called in a model itself

Comment: when i use this foreach i got some error:   Undefined variable: eventsave (View: /home/mariusz/Pulpit/www/szpital/resources/views/profil/profil.blade.php)

Comment: and when i use  $zapisevent->eventsave['name']   i got error Undefined index: name (View: /home/mariusz/Pulpit/www/szpital/resources/views/profil/profil.blade.php)

Comment: How i should called this name in model i really dont understand this

Answer (score 0):

When using arrays, you need to access their properties via their index like this:

`$zapisevent->eventsave['name']`

as opposed to:

`$zapisevent->eventsave->name`